# Understanding the function bind behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bind, borrow-checker

I am just playing around with bind. And wanted to understand the below code -

```
let admin = {
    name: "admin",
    id: 1,
    create() {
      return `${this.name} can create`;
    },
    edit() {
      return `${this.name} can edit`;
    },
    delete() {
      return `${this.name} can delete`;
    },
    read() {
      return `${this.name} can read`;
    }
  };
  
  let editor = {
    name: "editor",
    id: 2,
    edit: admin.edit.bind(this)
  };
  
  const editorEdit = admin.edit.bind(editor);

  console.log(editor.edit()); // undefined can edit
  console.log(editorEdit()); // editor can edit
```

Wanted to know what is the difference between the two console statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
  let editor = {
    name: "editor",
    id: 2,
    edit: admin.edit.bind(this)
  };
```

`this` isn't the object being constructed, but rather the `this` of the running context. Most likely the global object in this case. That's why it looks for `window.editor` (which is undefined).

`let` variable declarations don't get mixed up with the global object and you can't really reference the object until outside the literal (it just doesn't exist).

You can do:

```
let editor = {
   name: "editor",
   id: 2
};

editor.edit = admin.edit.bind(editor);
```

That being said, you could choose to not `bind` it.

```
let editor = {
    name: "editor",
    id: 2,
    edit: admin.edit
};
```

Should also work.

```js
let admin = {
    name: "admin",
    id: 1,
    create() {
      return `${this.name} can create`;
    },
    edit() {
      return `${this.name} can edit`;
    },
    delete() {
      return `${this.name} can delete`;
    },
    read() {
      return `${this.name} can read`;
    }
  };
  
  let editor = {
    name: "editor",
    id: 2,
    edit: admin.edit
  };
  
  let otherEditor = {
    name: "OtherEditor",
    id: 2
  }
  otherEditor.edit = admin.edit.bind(otherEditor);

  const editorEdit = admin.edit.bind(editor);

  console.log(editor.edit()); // editor can edit
  console.log(otherEditor.edit()); // OtherEditor can edit
  console.log(editorEdit()); // editor can edit
```

Comment: can we fix this?

Comment: Not inside the object literal, that I can think of. The object isn't constructed until after the literal gets parsed, so you can't reference it.

Comment: we can change 
otherEditor.edit = admin.edit.bind(otherEditor);
to
otherEditor.edit = admin.edit;

still will get the same ans.

Comment: Yes, they would both work. It all really depends on whether you actually need that function to be bound.